# Enviar datos a servidor desde aplicación Android mediante URL

Tags: android, http, get

Tengo una aplicación creada en Android Studio con API 28. También tengo un archivo php `http://mydomain/receptor.php` que recoge los datos de una url del tipo `http://mydomain/receptor.php?userid=23&points=123` y los guarda en la base de datos.

Lo que quiero es saber de qué modo puedo invocar esas url desde mi aplicación. He probado diferentes cosas pero no logro que la aplicación active la url. No necesito una respuesta del servidor en la aplicación, solo necesito que se active la url. ¿Cual es la forma más sencilla de hacerlo? Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 2):

Podrías hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class miClase {
    public void enviarDatosGet(){
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet("http://mydomain/receptor.php?userid=23&points=123"));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                //Todo Ok
            } else {
                //Algo pasó
            }
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Manejo los errores
        }
    }
}
```

Pero tené en cuenta que necesitás pedir el permiso de INTERNET en el manifest de tu aplicación:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

También deberías agregar la librería "org.apache.http.legacy" en el archivo build.gradle, de esta forma:

```
android {
    ...
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Espero te sirva.

¡Suerte!

Comment: Muchas gracias Gustavo lo voy a probar!!!

Comment: Después comentame si te funcionó! 

Comment: Hola Gustavo! Soy nuevo en esto de la programación en Android y me gustaría saber qué tengo que importar para que ese código funcione. también quisiera saber si ese código iría dentro de public void enviarDatosGet () { y aquí el código } Muchas gracias!

Comment: Ya completé un poco más el ejemplo para que puedas usarlo.
¡Suerte!

Comment: Muchas gracias Gustavo pero sigue sin funcionar. Llamo al método desde otra clase de este modo miClase cls2 = new miClase(); cls2.enviarDatosGet(); Pero no logro activar la url.

Comment: ¿No te da ningún error?

Comment: Hola! No me da ningún error. ¿Puede tener algo que ver el que esté usando el emulador de Android Studio?

Comment: Lo que he visto es que el código se detiene en esta línea "HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet("http://mydomain/receptor.php?userid=23&points=123"));"

Comment: ¿La url del httpget es la correcta?

Comment: Sí. Si la pruebo directamente en el explorador activa la respuesta en mi web

Comment: saludos, solo comentar que la respuesta de Gustavo Cantero funciona al a perfeccción